# if else statement inside a for loop?

Tags: java, if-statement

On the final part of a project i'm doing for school, I am supposed to use a `if-else` statement inside a `for` loop, but I have no idea how to do this. I could just use a huge lot of `if-else` statements to do the same thing, but I dont think my teacher would appreciate it.

Here are the instructions for the final part of the homework...

> Compute the Grade (A, B, C, D or F) and store in another Array8 called
>   grades using if-else loop and the following cutoff inside a for-loop
>   to assign grades.
>
> ```
> 1.    Average                        Grade
> 2.    >= 90                          A
> 3.    >=80 and <90                   B
> 4.    >=70 and <80                   C
> 5.    >=60 and <70                   D
> 6.    <60                            F
> ```

This is my code so far...

```
public class Proj5 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String[] Array1= {new String("Adam"),new String("Smith"),new String("Jones"),new String("Becky"),new String("Taylor")};
        Integer[] Array2={new Integer(90),new Integer(89),new Integer(86),new Integer(76),new Integer(95)};
        Integer[] Array3={new Integer(92),new Integer(79),new Integer(85),new Integer(90),new Integer(87)};
        Integer[] Array4={new Integer(93),new Integer(80),new Integer(90),new Integer(87),new Integer(92)};
        Integer[] Array5={new Integer(90),new Integer(77),new Integer(86),new Integer(92),new Integer(89)};

        double av1 = (((Array2[0]+Array3[0]+Array4[0])/3));
        double av2 = (((Array2[1]+Array3[1]+Array4[1])/3));
        double av3 = (((Array2[2]+Array3[2]+Array4[2])/3));
        double av4 = (((Array2[3]+Array3[3]+Array4[3])/3));
        double av5 = (((Array2[4]+Array3[4]+Array4[4])/3));

        double[] Array6 = {(av1),(av2),(av3),(av4),(av5)};

        double avf1 = (av1*.30)+(Array5[0]*.7);
        double avf2 = (av2*.30)+(Array5[1]*.7);
        double avf3 = (av3*.30)+(Array5[2]*.7);
        double avf4 = (av4*.30)+(Array5[3]*.7);
        double avf5 = (av5*.30)+(Array5[4]*.7);

        double[] Array7 = {(avf1),(avf2),(avf3),(avf4),(avf5)};

        System.out.println("Report for Spring Semester 2009"+
        "\n-------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Name Test1 Test2 Test3 Final Average Grade");

        for (int column = 0; column<Array1.length; column++){
            System.out.printf("%s ", Array1[column]);
            System.out.printf("%s   ", Array2[column]);
            System.out.printf("%s    ", Array3[column]);
            System.out.printf("%s    ", Array4[column]);
            System.out.printf("%s    ", Array5[column]);
            System.out.printf("%s    ",  Array7[column]);
            System.out.println(); //start new line of output
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Just fyi `if/else` is not a loop...

Comment: I'm just an ignorant programmer, but what's an "if else loop"?

Comment: @HotLicks I'm assuming the OP/assignment means `if/else` statement

Comment: words on the project sheet not mine :S

Comment: @SanctusSecretum You should not stay in that school then...

Comment: I think the assignment writer used "loop" when they meant "chain": `if ... else if ... else if ... else if ... else`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char[] Array8 = new char[5];

for (int i = 0; i < Array8.length;i++ ) {
    if (Array6[i] >= 90)
        Array8[i] = 'A';
    else if (Array6[i] >= 80)
        Array8[i] = 'B';
    else if (Array6[i] >= 70)
        Array8[i] = 'C';
    else if (Array6[i] >= 60)
        Array8[i] = 'D';
    else
        Array8[i] = 'F';
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`if/else` is not a loop. If you have to use an `if/else` statement in a `for` loop, just do it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Array8.length; i++) {
    if(...) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: you'll probably want to throw a `break` statement in there to exit the for loop

Answer (score 2):

It seems the assignment is asking you to write an `if/else` *chain* inside a `for` loop.

```
for (...) {
    if (average >= 90)
        grade = 'A';
    else if (average >= 80)
        grade = 'B';
    else if (average >= 70)
        grade = 'C';
    else if (average >= 60)
        grade = 'D';
    else
        grade = 'F';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If else?

If he means he needs it in the loop then I'm guessing that it's an if statement and an else statement inside the for loop. Or it could possibly be a else if loop, pretty much just the same except the else has extra conditions. Something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if(i < 5) {
        System.out.println("I am smaller than five");
    }
    else /*Or perhaps if an else if, 'else if(i > 7){System.out.println('I am bigger than seven');}'*/{
        System.out.println("I am bigger than five");
    }
}
```